# I want to change my desktop enviroment

Tags: 14.04, gnome, ppa

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and I like Unity, but I'm also curious so I would like to try out another DE. Few days ago I installed Cinnamon via PPA but that was not my style. I read good things about Gnome so I decided to give it a try.
I went to official Gnome site and I saw that I have to download the ISO file, etc, But I wonder, is there an official PPA to install Gnome 3.12 on Ubuntu 14.04?

By the way I found Moka's Gnome shell theme and I installed that, it works, but I don't know if that's a full feature gnome shell or not. Well I know it's just a theme, but it give a whole new feeling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.12 isn't that different from 3.10, so you can just install Gnome Shell from the official repositories without using the PPAs:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-tweak-tool
```

To install GNOME 3.12 on Ubuntu 14.04, you have to use the [GNOME3 Staging PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging?field.series_filter=trusty) (which itself depends on the [GNOME3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3?field.series_filter=trusty)). Be warned that this can break things.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell gnome-tweak-tool
```